# Transmission webui problem - Conflict 409

Tags: transmission

I am running the latest stable version of Transmission (version 2.31 from the Transmission ppa). Any time I try to log in to the web user interface, I get hit with this:

> 409: Conflict
>
> Your request had an invalid session-id header.
>
> To fix this, follow these steps:
>
> When reading a response, get its X-Transmission-Session-Id header and remember it
>   Add the updated header to your outgoing requests
>   When you get this 409 error message, resend your request with the updated header
>   This requirement has been added to help prevent CSRF attacks.
>
> X-Transmission-Session-Id: CBcYiodnQIHKYkhr9EceZOMW3ICgMSgt6j2FTCOXbcunA1tK

Anyway, I've had this problem with Transmission for the last couple of versions, and I haven't been able to find an answer as to how to fix this anywhere online. If anyone has any ideas, let me know.

Answer (score 55):

What is the URL you're trying to use?

Don't forget the trailing slash http://host:9091/transmission/web/ (it makes all the difference)

Comment: I don't even have apache installed. In the past, I didn't need to install or tinker with apache at all to get the webui to work. Also, I'm using URL format http://host:9091/transmission/web

Comment: sorry, misunderstood. Updated answer.

Comment: Omg, why the trailing slash is so important? I can't beleave that this resolved the problem.

Comment: Same here...unbelievable

Comment: @Sampgun It would make a difference if your browser stumbles upon e.g. `http://localhost:9091/transmission/web/?action=setsetting&s=password&v=backdoor`

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev yeah I know. I just couldn't believe the solution was so easy.

Comment: Still doesnt work with adding forward slash , transmission-daemon 2.94

Comment: I finally managed to access the webui by adding a `/` after `/transmission/web`, but the `/transmission/rpc` is still returning 404.

The transmission udp/tcp port is not visible publicly, is that an issue for the web client? How do I export UDP/TCP

Answer (score 4):

Try adding **`#files`** to the end of the address. e.g **`/web/#files`**.

It worked for me.

I was even able to take the **`#files`** off it once I had logged in and it still worked for some strange reason?

Answer (score 1):

I just solved this issue enabling the DMZ server in the router, pointing to the local IP of the raspberry.

Answer (score 0):

fwiw, I read the comment about the slash above and I am using the ttransmission remote gui.

I recentely added far more than my usual number of torrents to a seedbox and started reciving the session ID error and timeout errors as well in the client.

I was, however, able to access the web interface fine (it was just slow). I fixed the remote gui client by locating the URL in the settings and appending a / to the end of /transmission/rpc, so that I had /transmission/rpc/

this made it work normally except for the occasional timeout issues which i think has less to do with a setting and more to do with the sheer load (although it's only pushing 10mb/sec on gigabit down and 5mb/sec up (though that's just my portion if this is a shared box)